# Most efficient way to check if multiple relationships exist

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Let's say I need to find all articles, which are labeled with all three tags: `food`, `lifestyle` and `health`. What is the most efficient way to do that in MySQL? I came out with this solution:

```sql
select * from articles
where exists (
    select * from tags
    join article_tag on article_tag.tag_id = tags.id
    where article_tag.article_id = articles.id
    and tags.tag = 'food'
) and exists (
    select * from tags
    join article_tag on article_tag.tag_id = tags.id
    where article_tag.article_id = articles.id
    and tags.tag = 'lifestyle'
) and exists (
    select * from tags
    join article_tag on article_tag.tag_id = tags.id
    where article_tag.article_id = articles.id
    and tags.tag = 'health'
)
```

It works fine, but it looks like a lot of repetition. What is the most efficient query to solve this?

Comment: Astonishing! You expect people to help you with a query without telling us what your schema is. You furthermore want an "efficient query" without telling anything about the keys.

Comment: This is a theoretical, opened question. You can see the schema from the query, why would you need me to repeat it separately? And as for the keys, just assume they are where they should be (in the columns you match). You are one of these Stack Overflow sheep people, who expect question that don't make you think.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.*
from articles a 
join (
select articles.id
from articles
join article_tag on article_tag.article_id = articles.id
join tags on article_tag.tag_id = tags.id
where tags.tag in ('food','lifestyle','health')
group by articles.id
having SUM(CASE WHEN tags.tag = 'food' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN tags.tag = 'lifestyle' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
AND SUM(CASE WHEN tags.tag = 'health' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1) b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Sorry, you should list the columns you want to select in the group by clause, I edit the answer to solve this

Comment: But I want all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation instead:

```
select a.*
from articles a join
     article_tag at
     on at.article_id = a.id join
     tags t
     on at.tag_id = t.id
where t.tag in ('food', 'lifestyle', 'health')
group by a.id
having count(*) = 3;
```

This makes two reasonable assumptions:

- `id` is the primary key in `article` (or at least unique)
- `tag_id` does not have duplicates

Comment: You have a typo there, it's `in`, not `i`. Yeah, I know this approach, but for some reason I find it unstable in case of any duplicates in either `tags.tag` column or `article_tag` pair. I know there are Unique indexes our there, but sometimes they are not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
select a.*
from
  articles a
    inner join(
      select at.article_id
      from
        article_tag at
          inner join tags t
          on t.id = at.tag_id
      where t.tag in ('food', 'lifestyle', 'health')
      group by at.article_id
      having count(distinct t.tag) = 3
    ) at
    on at.article_id = a.id
```